# Ensure only one class can access a reference dll?

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I have a project where I want only one class to have access to a dll.  I would be content with hiding the dll from intellisense, but still having access to it if that is an option.  Either way, I want only one class to use the dll and for it not to be seen and/or accessible otherwise.
I'm using C# in visual studios.

Comment: Is this for security purposes or to enforce some sort of usage pattern?

Comment: Usage Pattern. I want a libraries functionality, but not for devs to accidentally use the library, because it will conflict if they do outside of the single class I intend as a barrier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply said: You can't do that (but keep reading).

Basically, a DLL (From the .NET perspective) is a bunch of code  and config files. No more than that. So, given that you'll need to make public those classes in order to be used from another ones outside that assembly then you can not.

What you can do (I ended up doing this a few years ago) is to use some kind of reflection to determine which class (and namespace) is trying to access your assembly and only permit the proper one.

Other way is to implement a key negotiation between your DLL and the permitted assembly. You'll need to implement those manually, as far as I know.

Anyway, keep in mind there's always a way to bypass this kind of protection by disassembling and modifying your code. So, at least, don't forget to obfuscate the file. Anyway, this will just make it a little more painful, but still possible.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach, if you goal is to stop people using the functionality of the dll by accident is to push your wrapper class into an intermediary assembly.  Your project then references that intermediary project, rather than the underlying dll which effectively hides it.  So your project structure would change to something like this:

```
Main Project -> references API Wrapper Project -> references API DLL
```

For this to work, your wrapper project needs to make sure that it doesn't accidentally expose any of the API DLL classes through its public interface.

Obviously this doesn't stop your developers from going in and adding a reference to the API DLL so that they can use the library directly, but if the goal is to stop *accidental* access to the API DLL classes because intellisense has helped the developer out a bit too much then it might be a viable option.